# Impressão de resultado da estrutura de repetição For não ocorre mas não apresenta erro, como resolver?

Tags: java, visual-studio

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Contador{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner terminal = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro um número de 1 a 20: ");
        int numeroUm = terminal.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite um segundo número de 1 a 20: ");
        int numeroDois = terminal.nextInt();

        try{ 
            contar(numeroUm, numeroDois);

        }catch (ParametrosInvalidosException e ) {
            System.out.println("O segundo número precisa ser maior que o primeiro!");

        } finally {
            terminal.close();
        }
        
    } 

    public static void contar (int numeroDois, int numeroUm) throws ParametrosInvalidosException{
        if (numeroUm <= numeroDois)
            throw new ParametrosInvalidosException();

            int contagem = numeroDois - numeroUm;
          
            for(int resultado = 1; resultado < contagem; resultado++){
              
                System.out.println("Contando o resultado: " + resultado);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: O problema é que no teu método `contar` você nomeou os parâmetros de uma maneira confusa. dando a entender o que o `numeroum` e `numerodois` lido no main, parecem ser os mesmos no método contar, mas não são, então ele nem entra no for, pois o valor é um número negativo acarretando que ele nem entra no for. (se usar os valores 1 e 5).

Comment: Problemas como este podem ser encontrados debugando a aplicação. Este [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7785/como-debugar-programas-pequenos) pode ajudar

Answer (score -1):

Seu codigo não tinha um else, então quando não atendia a cláusula valida simplesmente não fazia nada, sua conta de menos para calcular o for também estava invertida, além da contagem também estar incorreta segue o código ajustado:

```
package br.com.claudemir;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Contador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner terminal = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Digite o primeiro um número de 1 a 20: ");
        int numeroUm = terminal.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Digite um segundo número de 1 a 20: ");
        int numeroDois = terminal.nextInt();

        try {
            contar(numeroUm, numeroDois);

        } catch (ParametrosInvalidosException e) {
            System.out.println("O segundo número precisa ser maior que o primeiro!");

        } finally {
            terminal.close();
        }

    }

    public static void contar(int numeroDois, int numeroUm) throws ParametrosInvalidosException {
        if (numeroUm <= numeroDois) {
            throw new ParametrosInvalidosException();
        } else {
            int contagem = numeroUm - numeroDois;

            for (int resultado = 1; resultado <= contagem; resultado++) {

                System.out.println("Contando o resultado: " + resultado);
            }
        }
    }
}
```